# Google Icons won't align or float center

Tags: html, css, formatting, alignment

I am trying to add a center aligned google icon as a graphic within a div, above a headline and I can't align or float center. I can only align left or float left or right, but not center.

[Screenshot of icon aligned left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NCSk.png)

Neither CSS code has worked as I've intended.

```
<div id="comps">
      <div class="dark">
        <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">cloud</i>
        <h3>Competencies</h3>

.material-icons {
  text-align: center;
}
.material-icons {
  float: center;
}
```

Comment: ```float: center``` doesn't exist

Comment: Should both the headline and the icon be aligned or should the icon be centered above the headline?

Comment: the icon and the headline should be aligned center

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot from what it looks right now?

Comment: sure can- added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
    .center {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
    }
```

```html
<div id="comps">
          <div class="dark">
            <i class="center" style="font-size:48px;">cloud</i>
            <h3 class="center" >Competencies</h3>
```

Comment: Your answer isn't working fully.

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: Because he wants the text and the icon and header centered. And you have the class ```material-icons``` twice..

Comment: I modified it..